# Using Bold in the CONCATENATE function of excel

Tags: excel, concatenation

I'm using the concatenate function of the excel to merge the 1st and 2nd column along with some text.

```
=CONCATENATE("Check whether ",A2,"  is same as ",B2," value in Column2")
```

I get the 3rd column as the result but i want to use 'Bold' for the words in the 1st and 2nd column. I have a large data so cant go and change it manually. Is it possible to do it for all the rows at once.

Comment: You want to change formatting of part of cell contents? Impossible without VBA. Plus you shouldn't really do this IMHO as when you change the formatting of whole cells later, any partial formatting will be lost.

Comment: Can u help me using VBA for it.. I am not very familiar with VBA so i might need the complete steps...

Comment: VBA or some careful editing can change part of a string (aka *text*) value typed into a cell but not part of the string values returned by a formula; only the entire string.

Comment: Well, you can do something like `With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=6, Length:=10).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With` but it's complete hemorroids.

Comment: @danish bold is mandatory? you can single quote around values to highlight particular part in the output of the formula.